# TypeError: boolean is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I'm using SocketStream.

I'm calling `@session.save cb response`

The error doesn't happen until I pass response into the callback.

response is...

```
{ success: true,
  attributes: 
   { _id: 00000000,
     email: 'test@example.com',
     type: 'example' 
   }
}
```

Any ideas?

The callback is fired and everything works. The server just crashes with TypeError: boolean is not a function

Comment: "The error doesn't happen until"... what error? What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@session.save cb response` will execute the callback with 'response' as an argument, and then take the result of the callback, and pass it to @session.save. In thise case it looks like the return value of 'cb' is probably a boolean.

Without more info I can only guess, but maybe sommething like this is what you want?

```
@session.save ->
  cb response
```

Comment: Ahh, I see, yes that is exactly what was happening. @session.save takes a callback but it was getting passed a boolean. Thanks very much man!